# Countdown timer not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm not all that good with JavaScript, I can get by in a template, but can't build anything from scratch. Mainly, I code websites so I don't have to pay anybody else to do it.

I have a problem though, this countdown timer I got from a template for some reason won't accept a date for the countdown to "count down" to. All it will do in the `var` is allow you to put `null` and it then counts down to sometime in July. I have no idea why it is doing this. Here is the link to JsBin, although I don't use that often, so I'm not sure if I did it right:https://jsbin.com/tahageg/edit?html,js,output

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

    //custom 'this' selector
    thisEl = $(this);

    //array of custom settings
    var settings = { 
        'date': null,
        'format': null,
    };

    //append the settings array to options
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    //main countdown function
    function countdown_proc() {

        eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
        currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

        if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

        days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

        hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

        //conditional Ss
        if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
        if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
        if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
        if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

        //logic for the two_digits ON setting
        if(settings['format'] == "on") {
            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        }

        //update the countdown's html values.
        if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
            thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
            thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
        } else { 
            alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
            clearInterval(interval); 
        }
    }

    //run the function
    countdown_proc();

    //loop the function
    interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

}
```

`}) (jQuery)`;

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @user7345006 just shared JavaScript code

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Have you added the jQuery library?

Comment: @SergioAlen What do you mean "checked the console for errors"? And yes I did add the Jquery library, because it "works" when you define the date variable as null....but I can't define an end date. I've tried every format, and the countdown just shows all zeroes. BUT...when you set the date variable as null, it counts down, just at a pre-defined date and time that I don't seem to have control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using doesn't expect a Date object in the settings.date field. It expects a string which it will then parse.

This code `eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;` turns your string into a Date object and then gets the seconds representation of that date to compare to today.

So you can call the function as `$('#elementId').countdown({date: '12/31/2018'})`

Alternatively, you might want to look at a simpler implementation that doesn't use jQuery and has a completely working example and walkthrough https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Edit: changed date string to American format

Comment: I added that code exactly replacing the line you said was wrong and it just reset everything to zeroes again.

Comment: That's so weird...I can see it working in JsBin...but when I just copy and paste the code over, I still get the same result as I was last time (the timer counting down from some unknown time), in addition, this time the timer is like blinking as it counts down.

Comment: Can you see any differences in your environment to my jsbin that might be causing the problem? Did you include the final line I added that called the function?

Comment: That's what I was just looking for, any differences. And I don't see any. And yeah, I just took that JS from JsBin and just cut and pasted it right into my editor.

Comment: When you talk about the timer counting down from an unknown time it looks like it is being called from somewhere else. Are you sure there are no other calls of `$('#countdown').countdown(optionsObject)` in your code? When I call the function with no options object I get the error _"Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00"_

Comment: Just did a quick ctrl+f search for $('#countdown'). in all of my JS and HTML files, and there is nothing that matched that.

Comment: What about a ctrl+f of `.countdown(`? A different element might be given the function.

Comment: Would you look at that....I found .countdown(? called in one of my other JS pages...and it had the random date the timer was counting to. Just changed the date and it works! Thank you!